# Android app communication with a RESTful server

Tags: android, json, web-services, rest

I am working on an android app that will communicate with a RESTful API using JSON. This is my first android app that uses this ability and have not had much luck in finding 3rd party libraries on github. Is there a standard way to do this and what libraries should be used?

Comment: Use AndroidHttpRequest to connect to the URL, and JSONObject to parse the json.  What else do you need?

Comment: There are tons of tutorials and examples available all over the internet and you were not able to find even **one** of them?

Comment: @GabeSechan please vote to close.

Comment: Use Gson for this.This is powerful and fast for json handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the situation, you can use something like [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) or [Robospice](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice) to help with asynchronous communication. I've used both, Robospice is more robust but Ion is easier on the eyes.

Comment: Thanks. I checked with my server API developer and he said that Ion checks out.